# jQuery ajax call errors with sendToValue is not defined, what is wrong with this jquery code ?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm kind of new to jquery/ajax calls, I have this code below to pull from php page json values.

```
$(function(){

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    sendValue($(this).val);
});
});



function sendValue(str)
{

$.post(
    "back/search.php",
    { sendToValue: str },
    function(data) {
      if(!data.empty){
        //Put the result in the suggest div      
        $("#suggest").html(data.returnedFromValue); 
      }

    },"json"
);


}
```

and here is the search.php file

```
$values = $database->get_by_name($_POST['sendToValue']);   

if( !$values ) {

echo json_encode(array("returnedFromValue" => "ERROR"));

}
else 
{
foreach($values as $value) {

echo json_encode(array("returnedFromValue" => $value));

}
}
```

The problem that that the value doesn't appear in the suggest div, the only output there is "error", when I check the ajax request in firebug under post section it gives me the message that `sendToValue is not defined` any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that leaps out at me (there may be other problems, but this is the one I noticed first) is that you're missing the parentheses after `val` in the call to `sendValue`:

```
sendValue($(this).val);
```

should be:

```
sendValue($(this).val());
```

Currently, you're passing the `val` method itself into the `sendValue` function, rather than the result of calling that method.

Comment: oops, What a silly mistake ? i didn't realize that, all the time i was looking for the code it self and didn't think of that

Comment: An extra pair of eyes to look over something you've been looking at for ages always helps! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).val`probably needs to be `$(this).val()`

When programming JavaScript Firebug and `console.log()`are your friends.